# How to make objects inside an array work independently?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool

I have a mono-dimensional array containing 157 objects (instances) of a class. Each instance should work independently by checking and setting global variables. Everything freezes because the objects don't work separately. Everything gets stuck in the first loop of the first object.
I used an array instead of a list because I need the maximum speed.I created a sample mini project for you to understand the problem.

```
Module Module1

    Public global_variable As Integer
    Public array(156) As my_class
    Public counter As Integer

End Module
```

```
Public Class my_class

    Public Sub process()
        Do
            If global_variable = 536 Then
                counter += 1
                exit do
            End If
        Loop
    End Sub

End Class
```

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Static casual As New Random
        Dim mynumber, k As Integer

        For k = 0 To 156
            Dim mc As New my_class
            array(k) = mc
            mc.process() 'we never reach the next cycle, everything stops here.
         Next
        
MessageBox.Show("Ok, all objects in the array work!")

       Do
            mynumber = casual.Next(0, 2001)
            global_variable = mynumber
            If counter = 157 Then Exit Do
        Loop

        MessageBox.Show("Ok, Main Loop quitted! ")
    End Sub
```

Can anyone get this example to work? Thanks :-)

Comment: Because `Do ... Loop` does never end if the `global_variable` is not 536  and therefore the `Sub process()` never returns.

Comment: Note that `global_variable = mynumber` would be executed after the For-loop, so it has no influence on the global variable when `mc.process()` is called. Things happen strictly in sequence and not at the same time, since you are not using threads. It makes no sense to store objects in an array that do not store any state besides their own reference.

Comment: I know this. Indeed my question is just how to make the 157 instances work SEPARATELY. I used an array because real code obviously doesn't have to do just that. No need to post any more code. I did this to avoid confusion.

Comment: You must use threads! A good way to do this is to use the [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl).

Comment: I am not currently able to do this. editing this example by an expert would help me understand how tpl is used. can you help me? thank you

Comment: See [Parallel Tasks in .NET 4.0](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=489). There are examples in C# and VB.

Comment: I can't do it. Can anyone help me by modifying my example? thank you

Comment: Do you actually need a POLLING LOOP inside your class?...or do your class instances simply need to be NOTIFIED when the value changes, so they can make a decision? The latter can be accomplished by wrapping your global variable in a PROPERTY that raises a CUSTOM EVENT. The class will simply subscribe to the event when it is created.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use multi-threading then you can only do one thing at a time. Only when this thing is finished the next thing can be started.

```vb
Public Class my_class

    Public Sub process()
        ' Removed the blocking loop from this method.
        If global_variable = 536 Then
            counter += 1
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Without multi-threading, you must call `process()` in the loop assigning random numbers to the `global_variable`

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Static casual As New Random
    Dim k As Integer

    For k = 0 To 156
        array(k) = New my_class
    Next

    MessageBox.Show("Ok, all objects in the array work!")

    Do
        For k = 0 To 156
            global_variable = casual.Next(0, 2001)
            array(k).process()
        Next
        If counter = 157 Then Exit Do
    Loop

    MessageBox.Show("Ok, Main Loop quitted! ")
End Sub
```

Comment: you have been very kind and I thank you. I want to use multithreading, but I don't have the skills to do it. the examples I see on the internet are not suitable for making me understand how to solve my problem. I created this example just because I would like to see it modified to work in multithreading. This, as well as solving the problem for my real software, would finally give me a way to understand how multithreading works. In real software I'm forced to make each instance of the array work at the same time, I can't wait for each process to finish. Thanks again!